# there seems to be an error on line 39, i am unable to figure out what it is, please point me to my error?

Tags: php

created a login page however upon execution I am greeted by the following error :

`number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in ..\login1.php line 39`

Following is the code from login1.php, what have I done wrong?

```
 // query

    $result = $handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= ? AND password = ?");
    $result->bindParam('?', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam('?', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute(); //line 39
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: have you `var_dump`'ed `$result` to make sure it's what you think

Comment: @treyBake where exactly would I input the var_dump command, as when inputting it and trying to get the page working I still have the same error

Comment: `var_dump($result);` after the `->prepare` and after the `->bindParam`'s

Comment: In the bindParam, instead of using question mark '?' use the parameter index postion like                                                                                                                        
              `$result->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Answer (score 1):

you are confusing two different ways of binding values.  if you are going to use generic placeholders (i.e ?) then you need to pass the execute() an array of values in the correct order e.g.  `$result->execute([$user,$password])`.

if you are going to bind values then your placeholders need to be unique e.g. `"... WHERE username = :user AND password = :pass`

```
$result->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $result->bindParam(':pass', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

the benefit of the latter (which you are trying to use) is you can bind it once but use it in several places, e.g. 
`"...SELECT * FROM TABLE t, INNER JOIN TABLE_B b ON (t.col = b.col) WHERE b.id = :id AND t.id = :id ....`

```
$result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

even if you aren't going to bind individually but use the execute([array]) then you can still name your binds such as

```
$result->execute([':bind1' => $val1,':bind2'=>$val2 etc....])
```

it's always better to specify your binds to minimise the chance of binding the wrong value

Comment: upon making the relevant changes the error code has changed to " undefined index for the following lines: // new data
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

Comment: then your post variables are undefined, we'd need to see your form to help.  make sure each input has a name set

Comment: I just needed to refresh the connection and try to execute the page again, the log in attempt was success, thank you for the advice. the next stage is for me link a successful log in back to the home page, however I am going to save that for another day.

Answer (score 0):

In the bindParam, instead of using question mark '?' use the parameter index postion like

```
$result->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: it's better to explicitly name your binds, then you can apply them more than once if you need to and you minimise the chance of binding the wrong value

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way

```
$result = $handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= ? AND password = ?");
$result->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute(); //line 39
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```